# Where in the Tanya is a discussion of the concept of one soul - connection

Tags: tanya

The alter rebbe discusses the notion of one soul counteracting the notion of otherness.  Where in the Tanya is this discussion?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Judy and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: A pretty big theme of tanya is that there are 2 souls. Could you clarify what you are referring to?

Comment: I am referring to the Godly soul - not the animal soul.